# Nested Dictionary using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have some data with duplicates that looks like this:

| WEBPAGE | ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Webpage 1 | ID 1 | Value 1 |
| Webpage 1 | ID 1 | Value 2 |
| Webpage 1 | ID 1 | Value 3 |
| Webpage 1 | ID 2 | Value 4 |
| Webpage 1 | ID 2 | Value 5 |

Each webpage can have more than 1 ID associated with it and each ID can have more than one value associated with it.

I'd like to ideally have a nested dictionary with lists to handle the multiple IDs and multiple values:

```
{WEBPAGE: {ID 1: [value 1, value 2, value 3], ID 2: [value 4, value 5]}}
```

I've tried using to_dict and group_by but I can't seem to find the right syntax to create a nested dictionary within those.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
out = {}
for _, x in df.iterrows():
    out.setdefault(x["WEBPAGE"], {}).setdefault(x["ID"], []).append(x["VALUE"])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "Webpage 1": {
        "ID 1": ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"],
        "ID 2": ["Value 4", "Value 5"],
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately this didn't work, I have about 2 million rows of data and I think it struggled to process all of that.

Answer (score 0):

For a pandas approach, you just need to use a nested `groupby`:

```
d = (df.groupby('WEBPAGE')
       .apply(lambda g: g.groupby('ID')['VALUE'].agg(list).to_dict())
       .to_dict()
    )
```

output:

```
{'Webpage 1': {'ID 1': ['Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3'],
               'ID 2': ['Value 4', 'Value 5']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, using [`dictionary comprehension`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/dict_comprehension.html):

```
{x: {y: [z for z in df.VALUE[(df.WEBPAGE == x) & (df.ID == y)]]
    for y in df.ID[df.WEBPAGE == x]} for x in df.WEBPAGE}
```

Output:

```
{'Webpage 1': {'ID 1': ['Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3'],
  'ID 2': ['Value 4', 'Value 5']}}
```